# Comparing two string arrays with a Nested For loops

Tags: java, string, for-loop, arrays

Hi I'm trying to find matches between two string array using a nested for loops. However it seem to have looped around more times.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ca; i++) //ca contains 10
{
    for(int j = 0; j < ra; j++) //ra contains 10
    {
        if(cAnswers[i].equals(rAnswers[j]))
        {
            count++; //Increments count to indicate a match
            System.out.println("The current count: " + count); //To check the count
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("The number of correct questions is " + count + "/10"); //The result currently gives me 50/10 no matter what.
```

I tried using <= instead of just < but end up getting a index out of bounds.

Comment: What are the possible values in cAnswers and rAnswers? It seems something similar to MCQ type answers. If so, once cAnswers[i] matches something, shouldn't you break out from inner loop and go to next cAnswers?

Comment: Do your matches need to be at the same index or does it not matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every answer in `cAnswer`, you are going over all the answers in `rAnswer`.

```
String rAnswer[] = {"A", "B", "A", "D", "A", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"};
```

And

```
String cAnswer[] = {"A", "B", "A", "D", "A", "F", "G", "A", "I", "A"};
```

It will match `cAnswer[0]` with all `A's` in `rAnswer`, incrementing `count` by 3. Similarly, for `cAnswer[2]` it will again match all `A's` in `rAnswer` starting from index 0. Is this what you want?

If you want to do a linear match, i.e `cAnswer[0]` with `rAnswer[0]` a single loop is sufficient..

```
for(int i = 0; i < cAnswers.length && i < rAnswers.length; i++)
{
    if(cAnswers[i].equals(rAnswers[i]))
    {
        count++; //Increments count to indicate a match
        System.out.println("The current count: " + count);
    }
}
```

If you want to do something else, help us help you by providing more details.

Comment: Hi, I only wanted to match the cAnswer[0] with rAnswer[0]. I thought I needed a nested for loops in order to access each element. Your answer is sufficient enough and it works as it should now. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A nicer solution:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(cAnswers));
set.retainAll(Arrays.asList(rAnswers));
System.out.println("The number of correct questions is " + set.size() + "/10");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need nested loops for that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cAnswers.length && i < rAnswers.length; i++)
{
    if(cAnswers[i].equals(rAnswers[i]))
    {                           // ^
        count++; //Increments count to indicate a match
        System.out.println("The current count: " + count);
    }
}
```